# n^2 log n complexity

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I am just a bit confused. If time complexity of an algorithm is given by

[image]

what is that in big O notation? Just [image] or we keep the log?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If that's the time-complexity of the algorithm, then it is in big-O notation already, so, yes, keep the log. Asymptotically, there is a difference between `O(n^2)` and `O((n^2)*log(n))`.

Comment: I fully agree with that. Though it seems quite obvious I keep hearing people asserting that one can omit logN part because it's relatively small. That's why I've added a formal mathematical prove below.

Comment: @martin Just wondering, would this be considered a quadratic time complexity or a logarithmic time complexity?

Comment: @Jack, Neither. Logarithmic time complexity would be if you have O(log(n)) and quadratic if you have O(n^2). If you multiply these, you have super-quadratic time (but sub-cubic).

Answer (score 9):

A formal mathematical proof would be nice here.

Let's define following variables and functions:
`N` - input length of the algorithm,
`f(N) = N^2*ln(N)` - a function that computes algorithm's execution time.

Let's determine whether growth of this function is asymptotically bounded by `O(N^2)`.

According to the definition of the asymptotic notation [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), `g(x)` is an asymptotic bound for `f(x)` if and only if: for all sufficiently large values of `x`, the absolute value of `f(x)` is at most a positive constant multiple of `g(x)`. That is, `f(x) = O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a positive real number `M` and a real number `x0` such that

`|f(x)| <= M*g(x) for all x >= x0    (1)`

In our case, there must exists a positive real number `M` and a real number `N0` such that:
`|N^2*ln(N)| <= M*N^2 for all N >= N0   (2)`

Obviously, such `M` and `x0` do not exist, because for any arbitrary large `M` there is `N0`, such that
`ln(N) > M for all N >= N0    (3)`

Thus, we have proved that `N^2*ln(N)` is not asymptotically bounded by `O(N^2)`.

References:
[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to understand the big O notation is to divide the actual number of atomic steps by the term withing the big O and validate you get a constant (or a value that is smaller than some constant).

for example if your algorithm does 10n²⋅logn steps:

10n²⋅logn/n² = 10 log n -> not constant in n -> 10n²⋅log n is not O(n²)

10n²⋅logn/(n²⋅log n) = 10 -> constant in n -> 10n²⋅log n is O(n²⋅logn)

Answer (score 6):

You do keep the log because log(n) will increase as n increases and will in turn increase your overall complexity since it is multiplied.

As a general rule, you would only remove constants. So for example, if you had O(2 * n^2), you would just say the complexity is O(n^2) because running it on a machine that is twice more powerful shouldn't influence the complexity.

In the same way, if you had complexity O(n^2 + n^2) you would get to the above case and just say it's O(n^2). Since O(log(n)) is more optimal than O(n^2), if you had O(n^2 + log(n)), you would say the complexity is O(n^2) because it's even less than having O(2 * n^2).

O(n^2 * log(n)) does not fall into the above situation so you should not simplify it.

Answer (score 5):

if complexity of some algorithm =O(n^2) it can be written as O(n*n). is it O(n)?absolutely not. so O(n^2*logn) is not O(n^2).what you may want to know is that O(n^2+logn)=O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation :
`O(n2 + n)` can be written as `O(n2)` because when we increase `n`, the difference between `n2 + n` and `n2` becomes non-existent. Thus it can be written `O(n2)`.

Meanwhile, in `O(n2logn)` as the `n` increases, the difference between `n2` and `n2logn` will increase unlike the above case.
Therefore, `logn` stays.